# HP ALM Excel Addin - login+mapping via VBA Macro?

Tags: excel, vba, alm

im trying to automate the process of loggin into HP ALM Excel Addin + mapping.

so far ive got this code for login:

```
Dim qcURL As String
Dim qcID As String
Dim qcPWD As String
Dim qcDomain As String
Dim qcProject As String
Dim tdConnection As Object

   qcURL = "url" 'Example : https://<server url>/qcbin
   qcID = "user"
   qcPWD = "pw"
   qcDomain = "domain"
   qcProject = "project"
'Display a message in Status bar
   application.StatusBar = "Connecting to Quality Center.. Wait..."
' Create a Connection object to connect to Quality Center
   Set tdConnection = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
'Initialise the Quality center connection
   tdConnection.InitConnectionEx qcURL
'Authenticating with username and password
   tdConnection.Login qcID, qcPWD
'connecting to the domain and project
   tdConnection.Connect qcDomain, qcProject
'On successfull login display message in Status bar
   application.StatusBar = "........QC Connection is done Successfully"
```

but i get this error:
runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'TDApiOle80.TDConnection'

Answer (score 1):

You have to install ALM Connectivity Tool which you can download from your ALM server: http(s):///qcbin/PlugIns/TDConnectivity/TDConnect.exe